# Querying system that works with multiple versions of structures?

Tags: php, api, versioning

I am developing a `SOAP` `API` in `PHP`. This `API` should be able to handle multiple  interface versions. For this I am versioning data structures like:

- StructV1User
- StructV1Group

...and after some time...

- StructV2User
- StructV2Group

New data structures do not overwrite old ones. Multiple `API` interface versions should work simultaneously.

In the first version of the `API` interface an operation looks like:

```
User userGet(int id)
```

it returns an object that has the structure:

```
User {
    int id;
    string username;
    int created;
    int updated;
}
```

Suppose that after some time some properties were removed from the structure and others added (operation signature doesn't change in this example):

```
User {
    int id;
    string username;
    int updated;
    bool admin;
}
```

So if database changed and the field `created` does not exist any more it should be `null`. Old clients should check for null values.

**Notes:**

- There will be multiple versions of the `API` `interface`
- Database changes over time
- Each version has its own `URL`, its own `WSDL`, and its own `proxy class`

**How to create a querying system that works with multiple versions of structures?**

**Are there any known approaches for this?**

Answer (score 0):

*My first approach is to pass `callback` functions that are called for every row and transform data as needed:*

Here is the entry point:

```
function userGet($id){
    return UserModel::getUserById($id, 'myCallback'); /* Query system */
}
```

...and in the callback:

```
function myCallback($dbRow){
    $row = new StructV1User;
    $row->id = (int) $dbRow['id'];
    $row->username = (string) $dbRow['username'];
    $row->created = (int) $dbRow['created'];
    $row->updated = (int) $dbRow['updated'];
    return $row;
}
```

...and for the second version of the API:

```
function userGet($id){
    return UserModel::getUserById($id, 'my2ndCallback'); /* Query system */
}
```

...and in the callback:

```
function my2ndCallback($dbRow){
    $row = new StructV2User;
    $row->id = (int) $dbRow['id'];
    $row->username = (string) $dbRow['username'];
    $row->updated = (int) $dbRow['updated'];
    $row->admin = (boolean) $dbRow['admin'];
    return $row;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because its a soap Api can't you just give them a whole new URL when you update the structures?

Comment: I am doing this but behind I am using the same codebase because otherwise I should update all previous versions of the API if database changes.